# angular route is not find to route pages

Tags: angular, eclipse, angular-router

I new in angular. I am trying to route for my angular project among pages.When I go other pages,I am going to home page(http://localhost:4200). I searched some solution about problem but I never fixed my problem.Maybe my routing pages not finding correct path?
Here app.routing.module.ts

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      {path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'dashboard'},
      {path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: './pages/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'},
      {path: 'issue', loadChildren: './pages/issue/issue.module#IssueModule'},
      {path: 'project', loadChildren: './pages/project/project.module#ProjectModule'}
    ]
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

app.component.html

```
<div>
<h1>
Welcome to {{title}}!
</h1>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Here app.module.ts

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {AppRoutingModule} from './app.routing.module';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

dashboard.module

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
    import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';
    import { DashboardRoutingModule } from './dashboard.routing.module';



    @NgModule({

      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        DashboardRoutingModule,
       ],
      declarations: [DashboardComponent]
    })
    export class DashboardModule { }
dahsboard.routing.module.ts
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {DashboardComponent} from './dashboard.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: DashboardComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class DashboardRoutingModule {
}
```

My ide is eclipse because I am working about java ee and angular plugin loaded in eclipse.

Comment: First of all: you don't need that {path: '', children:}... Just use your children array as an array of routes. 

Second: check your angular version and the way you load children. You use a deprecated way to load children.

Comment: works for me , thank you :)

Comment: Ok, I posted it as an answer. You can approve it now.